# Adding int into a vector

Tags: c++, vector, while-loop, cin

I have just started learning c++ and I have this little problem. I try to put as many ints as I input to a vector and stop when I no longer input a int.

For that I use

```
while(std::cin>>x) v.push_back(x);
```

That is what I learn in my textbook, the problem is that whenever i put any character that is not a int the program stop even if there is another cin later in my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
  try{
    int x,n;
    int sum=0;
    std::vector<int> v;

    std::cout << "Introduce your numbers" << '\n';
    while(std::cin>>x) v.push_back(x);

    std::cout << "How many of them you want to add?" << '\n';
    std::cin >> n;

    if(n>v.size()) throw std::runtime_error("Not enough numbers in 
the vector");

    for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
       sum+=v[i];
    }

    std::cout<<sum;
    return 0;
    }

  catch(std::exception &exp){
    std::cout << "runtime_error" <<exp.what()<< '\n';
    return 1;
  }   
}
```

Comment: `std::cin >> ` will return `false` on failure. That's the expected behaviour. If you want to handle invalid inputs, you need to do that by yourself.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen No it won't. It will only ever return a reference to the stream. But that evaluates falsey when there's an error flag set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `std::cin>>x` fails because it encounters a character, that character isn't removed. So when you try to get another integer later, it will fail for the same reason. You can clean up the steam by flushing the buffer with `std::cin.ignore` and by resetting the error flag with `std::cin.clear`. After this line:

```
while(std::cin>>x) v.push_back(x);
```

Add this:

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
```

This way the stream is empty and ready again on the `std::cin >> n;` line where you try to read in another integer.

Comment: *std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX);* *~>* std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

Comment: This is assuming that a newline delimits the non-numeric input

Comment: @Caleth you're right. Is there a general solution that will clear the buffer no matter what?

Comment: Thanks, it works :) Although I dont understand (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n') and it keep working even if I remove it

Comment: @Caleth yes, no, not really. If there is no newline ignore() will keep discarding characters till eof.

Comment: @Alejandro `ignore` has to be told the maximum amount of characters that it ignores. `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` evaluates to the maximum size of the stream, so effectively there's no limit. So it just says "ignore all characters until a `\n`"

Comment: @Blaze *maximum size of the string ~>* maximum size of the stream

Comment: There isn't a general solution to "skip the wrong characters", because there isn't a general definition of "wrong characters". It will always be specific to what you are reading